# How can i save Text to Speech file as .wav/.mp3 format in Arabic language in External Storage?

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I want to save audio file in Arabic language. for that I am using the code as below.
i am trying it, but I am not able to save in Arabic language. its saves only in English language.
please help me, Thanks

```
package com.t;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.HashMap;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.os.Environment;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.OnInitListener;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class TextToSpeechNewActivity extends Activity {

Button store, play;
EditText input;
String speakTextTxt;
TextToSpeech mTts;
HashMap<String, String> myHashRender = new HashMap<String, String>();
String tempDestFile ;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    store = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    store.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            speakTextTxt = input.getText().toString();
            Log.v("log", ""+input.getText().toString());

            myHashRender.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID,speakTextTxt);

            String exStoragePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
            File appTmpPath = new File(exStoragePath + "/pradip");
            appTmpPath.mkdirs();
            String tempFilename = input.getText().toString()+".wav";
            tempDestFile = appTmpPath.getAbsolutePath() + "/"+ tempFilename;
            new MySpeech(speakTextTxt);

        }
    });
}

class MySpeech implements OnInitListener{

            String tts;

    public MySpeech(String tts)
    {
        this.tts = tts;
        mTts = new TextToSpeech(TextToSpeechNewActivity.this, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) 
    {
        Log.v("log", "initi");
        mTts.synthesizeToFile(speakTextTxt, myHashRender, tempDestFile);
    }
  }
 }
```

Comment: This may sound a little obvious, but have you tried explicitly setting the language to an Arabic `Locale` using [`setLanguage(...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#setLanguage%28java.util.Locale%29)? You can potentially also first check if the `Locale` is available by checking the return value of [`isLanguageAvailable(...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#isLanguageAvailable%28java.util.Locale%29)

Comment: thanks...i used    Locale loc = new Locale("es","MEX");  mTts.setLanguage(loc); This is for maxico and what code for Arabic of Saudi Arabia ?

Comment: Get them from Wikipedia: [ISO 3166-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1#Officially_assigned_code_elements) and [ISO 639-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes). Do note that the [`Locale` docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html) say: *"The language codes are two-letter lowercase ISO language codes (such as "en") as defined by ISO 639-1. The country codes are **two-letter** uppercase ISO country codes (such as "US") as defined by ISO 3166-1."*

Comment: Thank you so much It'z working rocks..

Answer (score 0):

From earlier comments:

> This may sound a little obvious, but have you tried explicitly setting the language to an Arabic `Locale` using [`setLanguage(...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#setLanguage%28java.util.Locale%29)? You can potentially also first check if the `Locale` is available by checking the return value of [`isLanguageAvailable(...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#isLanguageAvailable%28java.util.Locale%29)

And:

> Get them from Wikipedia: [ISO 3166-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1#Officially_assigned_code_elements) and [ISO 639-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes). Do note that the [`Locale` docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html) say: *"The language codes are two-letter lowercase ISO language codes (such as "en") as defined by ISO 639-1. The country codes are **two-letter** uppercase ISO country codes (such as "US") as defined by ISO 3166-1."*